# UITapGestureRecognizer with target - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I tried to make a simple tap gesture and I can't figure it out. I want to add a target, simple selector to the gesture.

Here is my code :

```
var panGesture : UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(<#UIGestureRecognizer#>)
```

How can I set selector?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Should look something like this:

```
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "SomeMethod")
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: Just gonna say that naming a `TapGesture` `panGesture` is in bad form (and I know you were copying the OP)

Comment: Haha, changed it, I had written the entire thing as a pan gesture at first, realized the question was for a tap and I forgot to change the var name.

Comment: are you supposed to import something other than UIKit? I cant get this to work!

Comment: _let tapGesture_ better than _var tapGesture_

Comment: If the tap gesture is added to a `UIImageView` make sure that you have set `userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: As of Swift 3, this no longer works. Please see below answer by @Alvin George  `let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(gesture:)))`  is how I got it to work.

Answer (score 10):

***Swift 3:***

*Adding Tap Gesture Target:*

```
sampleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.sampleTapGestureTapped(recognizer:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(sampleTapGesture!)
```

*Associated Function:*

```
func sampleTapGestureTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Tapping working")
    }
```