# How to dismiss keyboard when touching anywhere outside UITextField (in swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I'm working on a project that have a UIViewController, on the view controller there is a UIScrollView and a UITextField on the scrollview.
like this:
[image]
I'm trying to dismiss the keyboard and hide it after typing some text in the textfield and tap anywhere outside the textfield.
I've tried the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textField.delegate = self;
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

It works for me when I tap outside the scrollview, but when I tap on the scrollview nothing happens and the keyboard doesn't hide.

Is there any way to dismiss the keyboard when tapping **anywhere** outside the textfield?
thanks

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**Edited for Swift 4**

Edit: Added `@objc`.  While this isn't the best option for performance, one instance of it here shouldn't cause too many problems until there is a better solution.

**Edited to fix when needing to interact with items behind GestureRecognizer.**

Edit: Thanks @Rao for pointing this out.  Added `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false`.

This should help you with having multiple `UITextView` or `UITextField`

Create an extension of the view controller. This has worked much smoother for me and with less hassle than trying to use `.resignFirstResponder()`

```
extension UIViewController
{
    func setupToHideKeyboardOnTapOnView()
    {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))

        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard()
    {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Call `self.setupToHideKeyboardOnTapOnView()` in the viewDidLoad

Comment: I had to add 
 @objc func dismissKeyboard()
in Swift 4

Comment: @MCR you are correct.  I updated the answer to reflect that until I can find a more definitive approach.

Comment: Caution: If you have say, a tableView on the same view, this code will block the cell tap and your didSelectRow won't trigger. In order to avoid this you will need to add `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false` before `addGestureRecognizer`

Comment: Does anyone know how to prevent `dismissKeyboard()` from being called if the tap was done in a view that is embedded in a `UIViewContainer` in self?

Answer (score 61):

Try this, it's tested and working:

**For Swift 3.0 / 4.0**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

**For Older Swift**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me when tapping on the UIScrollView

Comment: Note this has been changed to override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) in Swift 2

Comment: @WhiteHat see my answer above for a Swift 3 answer that works with a ScrollView

Comment: This answer works with **Swift 4** as well !! Thanks.

Comment: @Hemang As @Rao stated in a comment on the accepted answer, you need to add `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false` when you have a TableView. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 17):

swift 3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In this case, there is UITapGesture as one of the choices. I tried to create sample code just in case. Like this,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap:")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func tap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I have another problem, I have a view controller with 5 textfields. is there a good way to do the same without calling "resignFirstResponder" method for them one by one?

Comment: another question, is there any way dismiss the keyboard when I tap any where outside the textfield? for example when I tap on a button?

Comment: @white-hat Could you ask that question as a another question?

Comment: @WhiteHat Put your 5 text fields in an outlet collection. Then create a dismissKeyboard method that iterates over the collection and calls resignFirstResponder on each text field. You can call this method from both the gesture recognizer and the button actions.

Comment: @WhiteHat ViewController.View could call endEdting

Answer (score 11):

**Working Solution for Swift 3 that works with ScrollView**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // The next line is the crucial part
        // The action is where Swift 3 varies from previous versions
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(gesture:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func tap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085922/uitapgesturerecognizer-with-target-swift/24086215#24086215) that talks about this issue that I referenced and used. The accepted answer no longer works in Swift 3. The current selected answer should be the below answer.

Comment: @JoeBlow I believe you are wrong. You are supposed to be resigning the first responder of the textField. Not the view. I have this code in my current project, and just tested it in a new project. Not to mention, my answer is just a newer version of the answer written by Pixyzehn.

Comment: hey dev @Devbot10 - don't hesitate to edit it back to what you had before man.  you know, I may have been confusing with `.endEditing`, which indeed recurses through all views below.

Answer (score 5):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution 1

[endEditing(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting)

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: tableView, action: #selector(UITextView.endEditing(_:)))
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

### Usage of solution 1. Full sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 30))
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.placeholder = "Enter text"
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        view.addSubview(textField)
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

> class TapGestureRecognizer

```
import UIKit

class TapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {

    let identifier: String

    init(target: Any?, action: Selector?, identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }

    static func == (left: TapGestureRecognizer, right: TapGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return left.identifier == right.identifier
    }
}
```

> extension UIView

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    private var hideKeybordOnTapIdentifier: String { return "hideKeybordOnTapIdentifier" }

    private var hideKeybordOnTapGestureRecognizer: TapGestureRecognizer? {
        let hideKeyboardGesture = TapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIView.hideKeyboard),
                                                       identifier: hideKeybordOnTapIdentifier)
        if let gestureRecognizers = self.gestureRecognizers {
            for gestureRecognizer in gestureRecognizers {
                if let tapGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? TapGestureRecognizer,
                    tapGestureRecognizer == hideKeyboardGesture {
                    return tapGestureRecognizer
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    @objc private func hideKeyboard() { endEditing(true) }

    var hideKeyboardOnTap: Bool {
        set {
            let hideKeyboardGesture = TapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard),
                                                           identifier: hideKeybordOnTapIdentifier)
            if let hideKeybordOnTapGestureRecognizer = hideKeybordOnTapGestureRecognizer {
                removeGestureRecognizer(hideKeybordOnTapGestureRecognizer)
                if gestureRecognizers?.count == 0 { gestureRecognizers = nil }
            }
            if newValue { addGestureRecognizer(hideKeyboardGesture) }
        }
        get { return hideKeybordOnTapGestureRecognizer == nil ? false : true }
    }
}
```

### Usage of solution 2

```
view.hideKeyboardOnTap = true
```

### Solution 2 full Sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 30))
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.placeholder = "Enter text"
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        view.addSubview(textField)
        view.hideKeyboardOnTap = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check this out.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap))
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

Then your tap handler is.

```
  func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: `imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)` should be `self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)`

Comment: Yeah sorry i  didn't notice. what im typing.  Thank you @AhsanEbrahim

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works when touched outside input area for any  number of input items.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i finally solved it !

Set a TapGestureRecognizer in your Storyboard and then an Outlet in your ViewController

```
@IBOutlet var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!
```

Then set an IBAction in your ViewController

```
@IBAction func DismissKeyboard(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
 self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

add these lines to your viewDidLoad method

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

and its should work

Hope that will help !

Answer (score 1):

Every touch different of *text field* dismiss the keyboard or use `resignfirstresponder`

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 if(![touch.view isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
     [touch.view endEditing:YES];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func findAndResignFirstResponder(_ stView: UIView) -> Bool {

    if stView.isFirstResponder {
        stView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    for subView: UIView in stView.subviews {
        if findAndResignFirstResponder(subView) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this method in Obj-C that hides a keyboard no matter where the user is currently typing:

```
//call this method
+ (void)hideKeyboard {
    //grab the main window of the application
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    //call our recursive method below
    [self resignResponderForView:window];
}

//our recursive method
+ (void)resignResponderForView:(UIView *)view {
    //resign responder from this view
    //If it has the keyboard, then it will hide the keyboard
    [view resignFirstResponder];
    //if it has no subviews, then return back up the stack
    if (view.subviews.count == 0)
        return;
    //go through all of its subviews
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        //recursively call the method on those subviews
        [self resignResponderForView:subview];
    }
}
```

I hope that that is translate-able into Swift and makes sense. It can be called anywhere in the application and will hide the keyboard no matter what VC you're on or anything.

Comment: You might want to check out [`-[UIView endEditing:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/endEditing:).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Keyboard Type and Select Default or whatever you need the TextField for. Then override a method call it whatever you want i usually call it touchingBegins. Below is what you forgot to add

```
super.touchingBegins(touches, withEvent: event)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a tap gesture recogniser and set and action for it.

Use the code:

*nameofyourtextfield*.resignfirstresponder()

Answer (score 0):

//In swift 4..It worked for me.

```
func setupKeyboardDismissRecognizer(){
    let tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(searchingActivity.dismissKeyboard))

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

    @objc func dismissKeyboard()
    {
        view.endEditing(true)
        searchTableView.isHidden = true
    }
```

//Call this function setupKeyboardDismissRecognizer() in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

In Swift4

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4 or 5 You can use like..**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Key borad dismiss
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  }

 //Key board hide on outside the textfield
 @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code in Swift 4, you can try this,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // dismiss keyboard when tap outside a text field 
    let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewControllerName.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

//Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```