# The keyboard does not close when I tap on the screen

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am implementing keyboard close as follows but it doesn't work.

```
extension SleepDiaryViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

[image]

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: view.endEditing(true)

Comment: yes i tried that

Comment: Tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41670675/6576315 ?